# Android Studio moves new files from kotlin into java package

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm starting a new Kotlin project in Android Studio and wanted to rename the `java` package to `kotlin`.

I added these lines of code into the `build.gradle` file,

```
main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
```

Android Studio recognized the `kotlin` package as the source directory, but when I create a new File/Activity a new `java` source directory is created in `src/main` and the File is added in this directory.

Android Studio creates the java directory and moves all files to it.

[image]

How can I get rid of the java directory so I just have `kotlin` directory?

**Update**: I can even reproduce this with a new empty project.

Comment: It's not the described visibility bug. The new files are automatically moved to a new java directory.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you, [edit] your question and post screenshots of Android Studio. This way we can easily understand the problem you're explaining here.

Comment: Thought my explanation was enough. But sure I added a screenshot.

Comment: anything on this?